# What to do if your question on AskUbuntu does not get answered?

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

I really need the answer, can I post my question again?

Comment: Which question is it? I'm happy to put a bounty on it for you. Also, you can help yourself a bit by looking at your existing questions and either accepting any helpful answers, revising the original questions, or looking for duplicates & near-duplicates.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/265351/zte-mf-691-usb-modem-connected-but-not-able-to-access-internet

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In addition to what [Takkat](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6350/22949) and [skunkfrkut](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6349/22949) have said, I want clarify a common point of confusion:

Many new users of Ask Ubuntu and other Stack Exchange sites assume their question will not be answered once it has dropped from the main page. But this is not the case--often questions are seen and answered even after they're no longer shown on the main page of the site.

This is because:

- The [Community♦](https://askubuntu.com/users/-1/community) bot automatically and randomly bumps questions back up to the top, so they are seen.
- There are multiple ways to view questions--the "main page" is just one tab of several.
- People often find questions they can answer, either deliberately or while working on something else, by running searches and checking the search results.
- People sometimes find questions they can answer in the automatically generated list of *related* questions, on another question they happen to be looking at.
- Tags often have subscribers, who are notified of questions with the tag.
- Someone who has seen something else you've written may be interested in your work and check your profile, then find your question.
- People often find questions by searching for Google (usually when trying to find an answer to their own issue).
- It is very common for people to find questions that they realize they can answer while [*in review*](https://askubuntu.com/review).
- People who use [the data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/ubuntu/queries) may find questions they can answer there (though that would be weeks after the question is first posted).

And, as something else *you* might consider doing:

- You can ask for help with your question in chat. Just make sure to stick around, and ask specifically for help, don't just post a link to your question without saying anything else. And try to avoid asking for help in chat and then immediately leaving before people have the chance to reply.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I will keep updating my unanswered question as far as I can.

Answer (score 7):

Rather than asking a duplicate question (which is likely to be closed as such), consider editing your existing question, adding more information to make it easier for other users to help you.

Answer (score 4):

From our FAQ you can do the follwing [if you don't get a good answer](https://askubuntu.com/faq#bounty):

> First, make sure you’ve asked a good question. To get better answers, you may need to put additional effort into your question. Edit your question to provide status and progress updates. Document your own continued efforts to answer your question. This will naturally bump your question and get more people interested in it.
>
> If, despite your best efforts, you feel questions aren’t getting good answers, you can help by offering a bounty.

In case you need help improving your question you are also welcome to join the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room).

Duplicate questions will have to be closed.