# How can I bump a question if I already have all the information and can't bounty?

Tags: discussion

I own an [inactive question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/274241/what-is-the-recommended-widget-toolkit-for-ubuntu-desktop).

I've read [How can I bump my unsolved question?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3540/how-can-i-bump-my-unsolved-question). From that question, it looks like I should add information or start a bounty. However, I feel like I've already given all the info I can think of - it's not like there are logs or anything I could have left out. And unlike the guy asking that question, I don't have 7000 reputation for a bounty.

What should I do to get my question noticed? It seems like it's not super complicated; is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: There are quite a few benefactors around the site, asking (politely ) in chat can sometimes get you a bounty for your question. The best way is to gain more reputation so you can bounty it yourself :)

Comment: Your question is also a bit tricky as of now as the project is going through a transition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have anything to add and can't bounty the question, you *shouldn't* bump it (though if you can get someone else to bounty it, then in doing so *they* have bumped it).

However, **it's not necessary for your question to be on the front page to be answered**. There are many ways questions not on the front page can be answered, and the Community♦ bot automatically bumps questions onto the front page (though there's no guarantee that yours will be bumped).

For a list of reasons/ways that questions that don't appear on the front page still get answered, please see [my answer](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6352/22949) to [What to do if your question on AskUbuntu does not get answered?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6347/what-to-do-if-your-question-on-askubuntu-does-not-get-answered).

**One thing you can do**, as [Call me V mentioned](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6451/22949), is to post [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room). However, this is not *just* useful for finding someone to put a bounty on your question--people in chat may have insights into how you might solve your problem.

When posting in chat, it's best to follow some basic principles of Ask Ubuntu chat etiquette. As I said in [that post](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6352/22949):

> You can ask for help with your question in chat. Just make sure to
>   stick around, and ask specifically for help, don't just post a link to
>   your question without saying anything else. And try to avoid asking
>   for help in chat and then immediately leaving before people have the
>   chance to reply.

Answer (score 2):

Answer other questions so you can bounty.  Bumping is generally frowned upon.  Or pop in to chat and see if someone else is willing to bounty it for you.

I think nobody is touching that question because it's an opinion/programming language recommendation.

Comment: What about commenting on his post ?

Comment: If it's with the intention of bumping, it's still bumping.  I've bountied questions for others before.  Ask @Seth ...

Comment: @Suhaib  Commenting doesn't bump a post, only edits, answers and bounties bump a post.  And yes, V has added a bounty to a question for me before :)

Comment: @seth, Aha, thanks. I have upvoted some old questions and they were bumped too.

Comment: also, just to clarify: i asked that question not meaning "what do you think is best" but "what does Canonical officially recommend".

Comment: @Suhaib No, voting doesn't bump a question..